# How to have a uniform indentation

Tags: indentation

I have the following content on LaTex.

`First we need to know the equation of the curve. Since it crosses the $x$ axis at $x=1$ and $x=4$, it must be of the form $y=k(x-1)(x-4)$.`

When compiled (along with the other stuff above it), this results in what you can see in the image.

However, I would like the whole thing to be indented at where 'First' is. I have looked online and noticed the 'quote' environment is suggested, but I really like the default indent LaTex gives to 'First' and would ideally like this to be the case for each line. The 'quote' environment has a much larger of indentation...

How would I be able to do this? Any help is appreciated :)

Edit: to clarify, I would like the $x=4$ to be where the 'first' is.
[image]

Comment: \parindent=0pt will do it.  For a one off, \noindent.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Hello. No sorry I would like to KEEP the indentation on the first line, just have this carry the whole way through... so I would like the $x=4$ to be where 'First' is, if this is possible?

Comment: \hangindent=\parindent, but you have to repeat it each paragraph.  Also \parbox{\dimexpr \linewidth-\parindent}{...}

Comment: the image shows the standard convention of marking a paragraph by an indent of the first line, if you suppress that you need to mark paragraphs some other way, for example with vertical space, either way the layout depends on the markup you have used for the heading which you have not shown, please always post a complete small document that shows the problem.

Comment: This sort of thing is usually handled by environments using \leftskip or lists using \leftmargin.

Comment: Ok is it possible to define an environment where everything in a specified region is indented by some amount (ideally by the same amount the 'first' is indented by)? If so, how is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can play with this to suit.  I create `\specindent` environment to indent by an amount of the `\parindent` throughout the environment.  With that, I turn off additional indenting and therefore introduce a small `\parskip` to keep track of paragraph breaks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\edef\svparindent{\the\parindent}
\newenvironment{specindent}
  {\par\everypar{\leftskip=\svparindent\relax}\parindent=0pt\relax\parskip=1ex}
  {\vspace{\parskip}\par}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{specindent}
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{specindent}
\lipsum[4-5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works so well, thank you!!!